# How can I fix "Missing 'use strict' statement"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, use-strict

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  'use strict';
  $('#c2').hide('slow');
});
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="Header">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kinematic Equations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Newtons Laws</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work and Force</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li id="one">Newtons 1st Law</li>
      <li id="two">Newtons 2nd Law</li>
      <li id="three">Newtons 3rd Law</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="content" id="c1"></div>
    <div class="content" id="c2"></div>
    <div class="content" id="c3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this code I do get the message "Missing 'use strict' statement". I am not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: There is no error as such in the above code. How `use strict;` should not be in quotes

Comment: your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/6q86n573/

Comment: Where exactly do you get that message? And it sounds more like a linter warning, not an error.

Comment: @Bergi not sure it's worth commenting - user hasn't been active for over a year now

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Oh my, you're right. It's just the question appeared on the main page because FloPinguin has edited it...

Comment: @Bergi yee made that mistake too haha xD started writing a comment and was like oh wait, it's from '15 with no accepted or given answer haha

Answer (score -1):

You probably got this message from **Dreamweaver**. When you put `'use strict';` at the beginning of your script instead of putting it inside a `$(document).ready(function(){` the error message should go away.

But there is probably a setting somewhere to turn off the prompt or error messaging for `'use strict';`. It is not neccessary to use `'use strict';`.

Comment: where does OP declare they use Dreamweaver? (side note: who actually uses dreamweaver?)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs After a google search I found out that this message mostly occurs in Dreamweaver ([example](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2420994))

Comment: it's still no reason to assume - OP could theoritcally have some custom error logger attached - plus post is 3 years old - OP hasn't been since Sept '17 - not much point in answering the post

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Why not helping future google searchers having the same problem?

Comment: You found the error message on Google and posted an answer - I'm sure future Googler's will come across the same posts you did via their search ..